SwiftUI Nested ScrollView with Pinned Headers Not Pinning Horizontal Header
I'm working on a SwiftUI layout that involves a vertical ScrollView and a section within it that scrolls horizontally. I want to have two pinned headers:
A vertical pinned header ("Header One") that stays at the top of the screen as the content below it scrolls vertically.
A horizontal pinned header ("a", "b", "c", etc.) that stays at the top of the horizontal scroll section and doesn't scroll vertically, but allows the content below it to scroll horizontally.
However, I'm only able to pin the vertical header while the horizontal header scrolls vertically along with the content. Here's my current code:
struct NestedScrolly: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            
            HStack{
                
                LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
                    
                    Section (header:
                                Text("Header One")
                             // give background here
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .background(.gray)
                    ) {
                        ForEach(0..<5) { item in
                            Text("Item \(item)")
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                
                
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
                        Section {
                            ForEach(0..<5) { item in
                                HStack{
                                    ForEach(0..<9) { item in
                                        Text("Item \(item)")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } header: {
                            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                                Text("a")
                                    .frame(width: 80)
                                Text("b")
                                    .frame(width: 80)
                                Text("d")
                                    .frame(width: 100)
                                Text("i")
                                    .frame(width: 80)
                                
                                Text("e")
                                    .frame(width: 80)
                                Text("f")
                                    .frame(width: 100)
                                Text("g")
                                    .frame(width: 100)
                                Text("h")
                                    .frame(width: 100)
                            }
                            .font(.caption)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .padding(.vertical, 8)
                            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        .font(.title2)
        .padding()
    }
}


Problem:
The vertical header ("Header One") pins correctly.
However, the horizontal header ("a", "b", "c", etc.) scrolls vertically along with the content instead of remaining pinned horizontally at the top of the horizontal section.
Question:
How can I achieve this layout in SwiftUI where both the vertical and horizontal headers pin correctly while allowing the content to scroll vertically and horizontally as intended?
Desired Behavior:
I want the horizontal header to stay visible at the top of the horizontal scroll section and scroll only horizontally, while the vertical content continues to scroll normally.
